# Use the same ApiControler to handle different structured Web Api requests

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I have a WebApi method which accepts a partameter structeded as an array of a class:

```
public JsonResult<ApiReportResponse<GeneratedReport>> GenerateReport(int reportId, CustomReportFormat reportFormat, [FromUri] ReportParameter[] reportParameters = null)
{ ......... }
```

`ReportParameter` class is defined as

```
public class ReportParameter: CustomReportParameter
{
    public string ParameterName { get; set; }

    public object ParameterValue { get; set; }

    public string ParameterLabel { get; set; }

    public bool MultiValue { get; set; }

    public CustomReportDataType? ParameterDataType { get; set; }
}
```

`reportParameters` parameter is optional

In calling this method, I either send a `Json`ified object string or structure request url as an object list like:

**`Json`ified version:**

```
var parameterList = new List<ReportParameter>();
parameterList.Add(new ReportParameter { ParameterName = "TestParam", ParameterValue = 1});
var url = "<report url here>" + "reportId=1&reportFormat=Pdf&reportParameters=" + Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject( requiredParameters.ToArray());
```

Url looks like this:

```
http://localhost:11111/ReportApi/Report/GenerateReport?reportId=41&reportFormat=Pdf&reportParameters=[{\"ParameterName\":\"TestParam\",\"ParameterValue\":1}]
```

But WebApi controller failed to catch this and deserialized `Json`ified string to `ReportParameter[]`.

**Direct URL request:**

I have a url like

```
http://localhost:11111/ReportApi/Report/GenerateReport?reportId=41&reportFormat=Pdf&reportParameters[0][ParameterName]=TestParam&reportParameters[0][ParameterValue]=1
```

This request can be handled by the Web Api without any problem.

How can I re-construct my Web Api method `GenerateReport` so it acn handle both?

Upadte: In failed `Json`ified request, Api method recieves an ReportParameter  object in the array, but all values of ReportParameter object are null.

[image: error]

Comment: are you getting null value for the reportParameters when you use jsonconverter in the api?

Comment: a better way could be to use `List<ReportParameter>` or `string` as the datatype for `reportParameters` argument in the api as you already have a `List<ReportParameter>` to serialize in json as `var parameterList = new List<ReportParameter>();`

Comment: Question updated @Niladri

Comment: check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

According to the JSON.NET documentation at the below link

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm

`JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` returns a json `string` after serializing the c# object. Hence you should use `string` as the parameter type for the api controller action . Follow the steps below

1. Do the serialization like below

   ```
   var parameterList = new List<ReportParameter>();

    parameterList.Add(new ReportParameter { ParameterName = "TestParam", ParameterValue = 1});

    var url = "<report url here>" + "reportId=1&reportFormat=Pdf&reportParameters=" + Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parameterList);
   ```

also note that you were using  `requiredParameters.ToArray()` to serialize the input where it should be `parameterList.ToArray()` according to your code.

2. Instead of using `ReportParameter[] reportParameters = null` as the argument you can use the below signature

   ```
   public JsonResult<ApiReportResponse<GeneratedReport>> GenerateReport(int reportId, CustomReportFormat reportFormat, [FromUri] string reportParameters)
    { 
      // do the null checking here for reportParameters
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(reportParameters))
         {
         // Deserialize it 
          JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ReportParameter>>(reportParameters);
         }
    }
   ```

let me know if you are able to see the values in controller parameters now.

Comment: I try this, but `[FromUri] string reportParameters` fails to match urls like `reportParameters[0][ParameterName]=TestParam&&reportParameters[0][ParameterValue]=12312`

I want a single api method that can handle both requests